# Trouble calling a Haskell function from the main module

Tags: haskell

I've defined a function called `findPaths` in a Haskell Module called BinaryTree and I am trying to call that function in the main module I've created. The type of the function call is

```
findPaths :: Tree -> [Path]
```

Where `Tree` is a data type defined as:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree
```

and `Path` is defined as:

```
data Path = LeftTurn Path | RightTurn Path | This
```

In the main function I'm doing this and only this:

```
module Main where
import BinaryTree
findPaths (Node Leaf Leaf)
```

But when I try and compile this with the following command:

`ghc -o --make Main Main.hs BinaryTree.hs`

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Q
                                    [Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Dec]'
against inferred type `[Path]'
In the expression: findPaths (Node Leaf Leaf)
```

I get the same error if I try to export the data types in the BinaryTree module:

```
module BinaryTree (Tree(..), Path(..), allPaths) where...
```

I'm at a loss... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Suggestions, no matter how straight forward and obvious are greatly welcome. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thank you, all of you, for your help.

@Travis Aside from what everyone suggested I ended up doing this last night before I read your message:

```
import BinaryTree

main = do
    print (findPaths (Node Leaf Leaf))
```

It works the way I expected it to. But in the future, I'll make sure I follow the proper semantics you referenced me.

**UPDATE 2**

I had responded last night with some other answers but apparently there was a [power outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67088/downtime-alert) and 4 hours worth of answers and questions were lost. Thought maybe I had dreamt answering those questions. Good to know I'm not crazy.

Comment: 2. Yes, the `show` is necessary if you're using `putStrLn` because `putStrLn` takes a String and a Tree is not a String. You use `show` to convert the Tree to a String. And the reason that you derived `Show` is so that there even is a `show` function for your Tree type. If you hadn't derived (or manually instantiated) `Show`, you just wouldn't be able to call `show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing this error because `findPaths (Node Leaf Leaf)` is an expression at the top level of your `Main` module, which [should only contain declarations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#declarations).

You can get the same error from GHC by trying to compile a file containing only a string literal, for example:

```
travis@sidmouth% echo '"Hello world"' > Test.hs
travis@sidmouth% ghc Test.hs

Test.hs:1:0:
    Couldn't match expected type `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Q
                                    [Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Dec]'
           against inferred type `[Char]'
    In the expression: "Hello world"
```

I have no idea why GHC gives an error message related to Template Haskell here—it's an arcane and confusing response to a simple mistake. All you actually need to do is change the expression to a declaration. The following should work just fine:

```
module Main where
import BinaryTree
paths = findPaths (Node Leaf Leaf)
main = putStrLn "Do something here."
```

Comment: GHC implicitly splices Template Haskell declarations at top level as of version 6.12.1: if `decls` is a value of type `Q [Dec]` you can just write `decls` rather than the traditional syntax of `$(decls)`.  This works even without the TemplateHaskell language extension enabled: a bug, which seems to be fixed in GHC 7: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4042

Answer (score 4):

To add to what Jonno_FTW said, you need a `main` routine in your Main module *and* it needs to do IO. So your `Main.hs` should be something like this:

```
module Main where
import BinaryTree
main = putStrLn . show . findPaths $ Node Leaf Leaf
```

Comment: That's right, the question asker seems to think that bare function calls in the Main module will get called in order...

Comment: I did actually, because I had done something a little similar before, so I figured it'd work. But looking at that code now, I'm seeing that I had `main = putStrLn "HelloWorld"` on a line followed by `insert 5 (Node 1 Leaf Leaf)` Where `insert` is defined in another module.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is in your calling of ghc, try this:

```
ghc -o main --make Main.hs
```